# How to check password requirements?

Tags: python, pandas, string, loops, data-cleaning

I have a database with 982 smaple username and passwords, and I want to find the ratio of bad passwords with these four criterias:

Password Requirments:

1- Must be at least 10 characters in length

2- Must contain at least:

- one lower case letter
- one upper case letter
- one numeric character
- one non-alphanumeric character

3- Must not contain the phrase password (case insensitive)

4- Must not contain the user's first or last name, e.g., if the user's name is John Smith, then SmItH876! is not a valid password.

I wrote the following code and my result was **0.64**, but the right answer is **0.75**, and I cannot understand what I have done wrong.
this is the [link of database](https://sessions.datacamp.com/proxy/absolute/f05fcab6-d6b8-4579-8aa8-ba89c1be7bf7/edit/datasets/logins.csv).

```
#Import modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('datasets/logins.csv')
#print(df.info())
print(df.head(10))

#Create first name and last name
first_names = []
last_names = []

for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    splitted = row['username'].split('.')
    first_names.append(splitted[0])
    last_names.append(splitted[1])

df['first_name'] = first_names
df['last_name'] = last_names
print(df.head(10))

#Check criterias
result = []
password= 'password'

for ind, row in df.iterrows():

    var = row['password']

    #check total
    check = True

    #check criteria 1 - length
    if len(var) < 10:
        check = False

    #check criteria 3 - password phrase
    elif password in var.lower():
        check = False

    #check criteria 4 - first and last name
    elif (row['first_name'] in var.lower() or row['last_name'] in var.lower()):
        check = False

    #check criteria 2 - characters
    else:
        check_l = False
        check_u = False
        check_nu = False
        check_an = False
    
        for char in var:    
            if char.islower():
                check_l = True
                break
        for char in var:
            if char.isupper():
                check_u = True
                break
        for char in var:
            if char.isnumeric():
                check_nu = True
                break
        for char in var:
            if char.isalnum():
                check_an = True
                break
        
        if (check_l == False or check_u == False or check_nu == False or check_an == False):
            check = False
                      
    result.append(check)
       
print(result)


#Calculate number of bad passwords
result_len = len(result)
result_true = sum(result)
bad_pass = (result_len - result_true) / result_len
bad_pass = round(bad_pass, 2)
print(bad_pass)
```

Comment: Try to print each password-check pair and see which ones aren't returning True when they should be true and vice versa. From there you can debug what the problem is

Comment: I can't download your dataset.